# facing routing issue in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, global-asax

I am working on project wherein there are 8 to 10 different types of project in a solution.
On sharepoint site there is one link say "open dashboard" ,when this link is clicked it navigates to the project I am working on.
Now the problem is when user click this link and a login page which is common for all the 8 to 10 project appears and depending upon selection from drop-down it navigates to that  particular dashboard.

Error occurs if user does the following steps :
 open two tabs in IE.  Navigate using sharepoint site and select the open dashboard and login to Project1.  if user repeat the same steps in the second tab, the error occurs(object reference not found).

I have created logs for this however I am not able to dig where the problem as it routes Project2(as an example) which is set default in route table but user has login to Project1 in tab1

what I want to achieve is that user should see same content in second tab as in first tab.

I have done tried so many things but they all are failing..Please correct me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Add exception details from your logs. If that doesn't have enough info, turn custom errors off in config. Also add your routes and other relevant details.

Comment: thanks Arghya, I added logs from which I came to know that its redirecting to wrong project(Project1) as in route table default one is Project 1but I want to add something that will make routing to the same project which one was called in first tab..kindly give me some guideline...

Comment: Sneha, add your routing details in the question (I think the routing only is not very confidential), and the sample urls that you're going to use. I'll try to find a solution.